# Django Auth : How are many-to-many relationship models created?

Tags: django, django-models, django-auth-models

`django.contrib.auth.models` have only 3 models, `User`, `Group`, `Permission`, as per the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/) and [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py).

Doc does say `groups` and `permissions` are many-to-many relationships.

But when we `migrate` how come other relations `user_group`, `user_permissions`, `group_permissions` are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tables for ManyToMany relationship are created by lines with **`models.ManyToManyField`** string that are in the migration file.

In this case they are created by the initial migration `django/contrib/auth/migrations/0001_initial.py`. It is very similar to `django/contrib/auth/models.py`.

The **related SQL** commands can be read by

```
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate auth 0001_initial
```

See the lines:
`CREATE TABLE "auth_user_groups"...`
`CREATE TABLE "auth_group_permissions"...`
`CREATE TABLE "auth_user_user_permissions"...`

Especially interesting two texts are around the words `REFERENCES`. That are the foreign keys to base tables, e.g.:
`... "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") ...`

---

**EDIT**:

You probably know a ManyToMany relationship joined by an explicit intermediate model specified by the parameter [through=SomeModel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) with an [extra field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

I explain it in **example** how you can **use a hidden intermediate table** in your code.

Imagine that you want to make a note to some permission why you added it to some person.

You can **explore** the model structure from command line, because in "auth/models.py" you could read only the name "user_parmissions".

```
>>> User._meta.local_many_to_many
[<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: groups>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: user_permissions>]
>>> User.user_permissions.through
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User_user_permissions'>
>>> User.user_permissions.through._meta.local_fields
[<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: user>,
 <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: permission>]
```

*your_app/models.py*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission
from django.db import models

# This line is instead of import, because the implicit intermediate table
# can not be imported.
UserPermission = User.user_permissions.through

class UserPermissionReason(models.Model)
    user_permission = models.ForeignKey(UserPermission, ...)
    reason = models.CharField(help_text="Why I added that permission", ...)
```

makemigrations, migrate, shell...

**Example: Create a user permission with your note**

```
>>> from your_app.models import UserPermissionReason, UserPermission
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission
>>> permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can add user',
                                        content_type__app_label='auth')
>>> permission
<Permission: auth | user | Can add user>
>>> user_permission = UserPermission.objects.create(user=me_superuser,
                                                    permission=permission)
>>> why = UserPermissionReason.objects.create(
        user_permission=user_permission,
        reason="Because I can :-)"
    )
```

If you don't need to reference the intermediate table you would use a normal simple `some_ruser.user_permissions.add(permission)`

Comment: I see that code, but did not find definitions for `many-to-many` models. Just `ManyToManyField` class. I am unable to wrap my head around that. :(

Comment: @KishorPawar I added an example how it can be used.